# Laravel 8 - General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the category_id (foreign key) of an input and store it in its book from a text input. It works when I manually add it with the id but couldn't figure out how to retrieve it from the input without having to change its the categories listing display.

***BookController :***

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{

    $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'author' => 'required|max:255',
    'editor' => 'required|max:255',
    'ISBN' => 'required|max:255',
    'language' => 'required|max:255',
    'year' => 'required|max:4',
    'copies' => 'required',
    'image' => 'required|image'
    ]);
    
    $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
    
    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->resize(350,500);
    $image->save();
    
    $book = new Book();
    
    $book->title = $request->title;
    $book->author = $request->author;
    $book->category_id = $request->category;
    $book->editor = $request->editor;
    $book->ISBN = $request->ISBN;
    $book->language = $request->language;
    $book->year = $request->year;
    $book->copies = $request->copies;
    $book->image = $imagePath;
    $book->resume = $request->resume;
    
    $book->save();
    
    
    return redirect()->route('books');
}
```

***Book Model :***

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

***Category input :***

```
<select name="category" id="category" placeholder="Categorie" class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg
          @error('category') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('category') }}">
@foreach($cats as $cat)
    <option>{{$cat->lable}}</option>
@endforeach
```

It's my first laravel project by the way.

Comment: You're missing a `value` for your Options: `<option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->label }}</option>`. Does it work if you add that?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Yep... I knew I was missing something in the input. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Sweet! Also, `<select>` elements do not have a `value=` property. If you want to set the old value, you need to do so on the `<option>`, like `<option value="{{ $cat->id }}" {{ $cat->id == old('category') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $cat->label }}</option>`.